# Suppose i have two lists in python a list of first names and a list of last names

Tags: python

```
firstName = ['abcd','efghi','jkl','mnopqr']
lastName  = ['xyz','pqrst','uvw','klmn']
```

my desired output is:

```
abcd xyz a.xyz@example.com
efghi pqrst e.pqrst@example.com 
jkl uvw j.uvw@example.com 
mnopqr klmn m.klmn@example.com
```

I have tried various methods and failed. The closest I could come up with was:

```
for x,y in zip(firstName,lastName):
    print(x,y)
```

What should I do?

Comment: do you want to output that in a file or just print to screen?

Comment: Where  are the email addresses coming from?

Comment: @thefourtheye they are obviously constructed from the name

Comment: output that in a screen as well as file

Comment: i am the one generating the mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints the output you're looking for. Did you really just want to print it ?

```
for x,y in zip(firstName,lastName):
    print (x,y, x[0] + r'.' + y + r'@example.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use basic string formatting and print the output like shown below:

```
for x, y in zip(firstName,lastName):
    print(x, y, "%s.%s@example.com"%(x[0], y))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for x,y in zip(firstName,lastName):
...     print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(x,y,x[0]+'.'+y+'@example.com'))
... 
abcd    xyz a.xyz@example.com
efghi   pqrst   e.pqrst@example.com
jkl uvw j.uvw@example.com
mnopqr  klmn    m.klmn@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
firstName = ['abcd','efghi','jkl','mnopqr']
lastName  = ['xyz','pqrst','uvw','klmn']

for index in range(0, len(firstName)):

    first = firstName[index]
    last = lastName[index]
    email = first[0] + '.' + last + '@example.com'

    print first, last, email
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,j in zip(firstName,lastName):
    print (i+" "+j+" "+i[0]+"."+j+"@example.com")
```

output

```
abcd xyz a.xyz@example.com
efghi pqrst e.pqrst@example.com
jkl uvw j.uvw@example.com
mnopqr klmn m.klmn@example.com
```